# Honda Accord not starting

Tags: honda, starting, accord

My 04 Honda accord 2.4L die randomly at a light. And now it won't even start. All it does is a clicking sound. I've replaced the starter and the alternator. Tested  the battery and nothing has fix it. Any ideas Any One??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: How was the battery tested? The symptoms you describe are classic of a battery with insufficient charge, though loose connections are not uncommon either.

Comment: Check the battery at AutoZone and try the battery from another Honda just like mine.